# How do I redirect to another page in my application using mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, single-page-application

I am using Web API MVC SPA application and I would like to know how to redirect to another page using javascript. I have pasted my code below but it is not working

This is the code I have at the bottom of my cshtml page

```
<input type="button" onclick="redirectToUploadPage()" value="Login" />
@Html.Hidden("RedirectTo", Url.Action("_test", "Home"));
<script>

    function redirectToUploadPage() {
        var url = $("#RedirectTo").val();

    }

</script>



 My route config  



 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );


    routes.MapRoute(
       name: "test",
      // url: "",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "test", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


       My controller

public ActionResult test()
        {

           return PartialView("test");


        }
```

In my browser it shows that it is trying to redirect to the test page because in my browser it shows `http://localhost:55851/#!test.cshtml` but it does not redirect to that page

Comment: maybe `window.location = "/test.cshtml";`

Comment: that seems to work better but I get a 404 error saying the resource cannot be found yet the page is located in the same folder as the login page

Comment: If it is mvc you need to redirect to the controller. Not the cshtml. This is not webforms.

Comment: thanks for the input please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="button" onclick="redirectToUploadPage()" value="Login" />

<script> function redirectToUploadPage() { location.replace("#!test.cshtml") } </script>
```